# How to create tables with columns that have range in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

**I want to create a table for the following:**

1. One pokemon must have and can only have one trainer.
2. One pokemon may evolve into many other pokemons.
3. The pokemon name has a maximum of 50 characters and can not be
   blank.
4. The dex number has 3-numeric-digit and can not be blank.
5. The pokemon height is a whole number and ranges [0, 1,000] cm
   inclusive.
6. The pokemon weight ranges [0.00, 1,000.00] kg inclusive.
7. The pokemon color has a maximum of 20 characters.
8. The pokemon type has a maximum of 15 characters. If an INSERT
   doesn't list the pokemon type value, it should default to Grass

I am stuck specifically on number 5. How do I apply that to my table? Also, another question is how do I apply numbers 5-6 and 8 also? How can I also assign the EvolvedFrom as one of the Foreign Keys? I don't know where to refrence it. I am a little bit confused, so please help. Thank you so much.

[Table Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d3gd.png)

[ERD of the table to be created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dir8V.png)

This is my sample code that I have created:

```
CREATE TABLE pokemon(
pokemonId int,
pokemonDexNum int(3) NOT NULL,
pokemonName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
pokemonHeightCm  int unsigned,
 CONSTRAINT CHK_pokemonHeightCm  CHECK (pokemonHeightCm  <= 1000)
pokemonWeightKg int NOT NULL,
pokemonColor varchar(50),
pokemonType varchar(50),
trainerId int NOT NULL,
evolvedFrom varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (pokemonId),
FOREIGN KEY (trainerId) REFERENCES trainer(trainerId),
FOREIGN KEY (evolvedFrom) REFERENCES pokemon(evolvedInto) --THIS LINE IS INCORRECT. HELP--
);
```

Comment: You can use check constraints. Specify which RDBMS

Comment: Please specify which RDBMS as well @mariakz

Comment: The one that I use is MySQL

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)   (The text in the picture could have been postes as text, not as an image)

Comment: Sorry for that, i have edited the question already, hope you can help. @Luuk

Comment: 1) Because `pokemonId` is a PRIMARY KEY, it will be unique, and a pkemon has only one field `trainerId`, show this is OK.

Comment: Does a row represent individual Pokemon? Or does it represent a species? Is it *a* bulbasaur or all bulbasaur? Rather than a varchar field, have a `pokemonTypes` table and reference it. That way you can only have defined types. Alternatively, use an enum, but types will likely have more attributes like what they're strong and weak against. `evolvedFrom` should be an `int` referencing `pokemon(pokemonId)`.

Comment: seems this is a homework

Comment: @Schwern i have attached the tables with sample data given to us and I am not sure if I can create a separate table for pokemonTypes...

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)   Please post sample data a text, or create a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) for it

Comment: @Luuk i don't have the copy of that, I only have the image that was given to us

Comment: I suspect a lot of more questions before this homework is finished  so, with your next question, you should/could add a dbfiddle which represents some sample data, to make that question into an [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Try to include a constrain as below.

CREATE TABLE pokemon(
pokemonHeightCm int() NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pokemonHeightCm_Ck CHECK (pokemonHeightCm BETWEEN 0 AND 1000),
... and the rest

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try the below, I haven't tested the syntaxes:

```
CREATE TABLE pokemon(
pokemonId int ,
pokemonDexNum int(3) NOT NULL, #rule 4
pokemonName varchar(50) NOT NULL, #rule 3
pokemonHeightCm int NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT CHK_pokemonHeightCm  CHECK (pokemonHeightCm  <= 1000), #rule 5
pokemonWeightKg decimal NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT CHK_pokemonWeightKg  CHECK (pokemonWeightKg  <= 1000.00), #rule 6
pokemonColor varchar(20), #rule 7 
pokemonType varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Grass', #rule 8
trainerId int NOT NULL,
evolvedFrom int,
PRIMARY KEY (pokemonId),                            #rule 1
FOREIGN KEY (trainerId) REFERENCES trainer(trainerId), #rule 1
FOREIGN KEY (evolvedFrom) REFERENCES pokemon(pokemonId)  #rule 2
);
```

Comment: weight is in decimal

Comment: `pokemonWeightKg ...(**pokemonHeightCm**  <= 1000)`  

Comment: I'll try this one. THANK YOU!!